# 1. What type of database, if any for information arrangement? 2. Faster with int instead of string values in database?

Tags: database, performance

I am collecting data from the internet at regular intervals and put it in text files

Columns: Datetime data1 data2 data3

Values:  20170717 1800 text1 text2 int

1. What kind of database would be best, where the data is predictable? I could rearrange the data for a column-base if needed. Then you have those saying you should not use databases at all (referring to Google).
2. Would it be faster and cheaper on disc space if I translate string values into simple int and have a separate translation table when queries are needed?

For instance writing 1, 2 and 3 instead of hockey stick, football and frisbee or 1,2,3 instead of Newport, Kuala Lumpur, Lumpini Stadium into the database and when searching doing *in pseudocode* INNER JOIN database AND translation-table WHERE 1 = Newport

Perhaps there would be trade offs between saving disc space and increasing the workload on the CPU when querying the database with INNER JOIN-type queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to look further into the subject matter. Data formats I did not know about popped up in the following video and then a good text on the matter.

[VIDEO: More parallelization file formats matter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WUgRpl-j7Y)

[TEXT: How to choose data type](https://www.svds.com/how-to-choose-a-data-format/)